# Override default value of an input field observable with that of user input and pass it to server

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a form with one **input field** called'Quantity to Issue' and **two display fields** called 'Planned Quantity' and 'Issued Quantity'.

The user gets to input a value in the 'Quantity to Issue' field. This also updates the value in the display field 'Issued Quantity' because it is bind to the same observable.

However, when the app starts if the value of my input field 'Quantity to Issue' is zero then I want its value to be initialized to 'Planned Quantity' which can help the user if they do not want to input any value.

The problem is when the user enters the value in the 'Quantity to Issue' field it does not get updated to the user value but is still bind to Planned Quantity.

I am doing this with a computed observable which checks to see if the value of the issueQuantity is zero. If it is ,then it assigns the value of plannedQuantity to issueQunatity and returns it.

In the computed observable I am using the write function. I am using this to update the issueQuantity observable in the case of user input.

The problem is that my write function is not working. The input field still has the old value and does not get updated with user input value using write function of my computed.

My fiddle is here...

[my knockout fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harrobbed/zLsk63nf/)

```
    var viewmodel = {
                issuedQty: ko.observable(0),
                plannedQty: ko.observable(10),

            };

 viewmodel.defaultIfNull = ko.computed({
                                read: function () {
                                    if (IssuedQuantity() === 0) {
                                        issuedQty() = plannedQty()
                                        return issuedQty();
                                    } else if (issuedQty() > 0) {
                                        return issuedQty();
                                    }
                                    return 0;

                                },
                                write: function(value) {
                                    value = parseInt(value);
                                     return issuedQty(value);
                                },
                                owner: viewmodel
                            });


 ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is this...

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/miketalley/2o3hfvfd/24/

The view...

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Planned Quantity</th>
      <th>Quantity to Issued</th>
      <th>Issued Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span data-bind="text: plannedQty"></td>
      <td><input class="a" type="text" data-bind="value: defaultIfNull"></td>
      <td><span data-bind="text: issuedQty"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

... and the viewmodel...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.issuedQty = ko.observable(),
    self.plannedQty = ko.observable(10),

    self.defaultIfNull = ko.computed({
      read: function () {
        if (!self.issuedQty()) {
          // This will run if 0 or undefined
          self.issuedQty(self.plannedQty());
          return self.issuedQty();
        } else {
          return self.issuedQty();
        }
      },
      write: function(value) {
        value = parseInt(value);
        return self.issuedQty(value);
      }
    });
  };

  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

});
```

Comment: Yes, that is how I want. You are right! But the write does not work in my case. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Your fiddle works and this is what I want in my app. But my app does not process the write. Should I create a custom binding? that reads a value and updates my issuedQty which is getting passed to the server.

Comment: I got it working now. Thank you for your solution. It helped.